# Angular2: ngIf without destroying component

Tags: angular, bing-maps, conditional-rendering

I have a web page with a `tab` control taking up a portion of the screen.  The tabs are shown/hidden using `*ngIf` and comparing the selected tab against an `enum`.  Thus the components are destroyed / created every time the user changes tabs.

Usually this is fine, but one of the tabs contains a `Bing map`.  Every time the tab is selected the map control is reloaded - causing the map to briefly display the `current IP location` until the desired location and pins are loaded (a fraction of a second later).

The only way I was able to get around this was to stop using `*ngIf` for that tab and instead set a custom style:

```
.hide { height: 0px; overflow: hidden; }
```

So far this appears to work great, but I am concerned that this will give rise to bugs down the road.

Is there an angular2 blessed way to hide a component without destroying the component?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe, You should use [hidden]="!myVar" approach in order to hide the element instead of destroying it.

Answer (score 21):

The `[hidden]` property is what you are looking for. It more or less replaced `ng-show` / `ng-hide` in Angular2.

Find it in the [offical docs](https://angular.io/guide/ajs-quick-reference#ng-show) or see their code sample here:

```
<h3 [hidden]="!favoriteHero">
   Your favorite hero is: {{favoriteHero}}
</h3>
```

Comment: Both [hidden]="" and "display:none;" have the same issue - the map code appears to be unable to configure the map.  From what I read, the Bing map should be visible when configured and then hidden afterwards.  [http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2012/02/23/optimizing-bing-maps-platform-sessions-and-transactions-usage/].

Comment: Hmm, I see. 1) The link doesn't seem to work. 2) Your question may be a bit misleading. It is actually not about "ngIf" and "destroying components" but much more about the specific requirements of the Bing map. I'd propose you start a new question making clear the particular issue with Bing. Perhaps you can even provide a plunkr for your case?

Comment: I suppose [hidden] will try to load everything situated in the markup at once. What if I need a bit different scenario: not to load the hidden content until the first time I access it, but once it has been accessed, do not destroy it, only hide?

Answer (score 2):

use `[hidden]` property of angular which does not remove the section/ component from the DOM instead hides it from the view thus there is no need of  reinstantiating the component in the DOM (similar to css `display: hidden` property)

- `[hidden]= true`  -> Hides the Section from the view but it **exists in DOM**
- `[hidden]= false` -> Show's the section in view
- `*ngIf="false"`   -> Hides the Section from the view & **Removes it from the DOM** as well